# Badge count on Floating action button

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to show count badge **in front of** Floating Action Button in android. I used FrameLayout in order to achieve that. My code is here

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/listen_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:backgroundTint="#e3e3e3" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/frameLayout" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I get the count badge below the FAB, as shown below

[image]

I need the count badge to be in front of the FAB.

Comment: From the design guidelines: "Floating action buttons don’t contain app bar icons or status bar notifications. Don’t layer badges or other elements over a floating action button."  https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button

Comment: Try `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for both elements.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [**`BadgeDrawable`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BadgeDrawable.md) provided by the Material Components Library.

Something like:

```
    fab.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(MainActivity.this);
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(2);
            //Important to change the position of the Badge
            badgeDrawable.setHorizontalOffset(30);
            badgeDrawable.setVerticalOffset(20);

            BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, fab, null);

            fab.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Currently (`1.3.0-alpha02`) there isn't a method to change the radius, but you can override this dimen in your project (`dimens.xml`):

```
<dimen name="mtrl_badge_with_text_radius">12dp</dimen>
```

[image]

Comment: attachBadgeDrawable is experimental

Comment: it seems getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener is not needed. I am using BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, fab, null); and I did not see any problems.

Answer (score 8):

For this problem solution is `android:elevation="7dp"`. But you are looking for something like this then use bellow code:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin.2">
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_cart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin.2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text.size.small"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_fab"
                tools:text="10" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

I used the [CounterFab library](https://github.com/andremion/CounterFab) to achieve this.

It is as simple as adding it to your XML layout file instead of the regular `FloatingActionButton` and calling `counterFab.setCount(10);` (See usage example [here](https://github.com/andremion/CounterFab#usage)).

Comment: It isn't working fine for Android 6.0 or lower versions.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Daniel, you should not add badges to Floating Action Buttons. However, if you really have to do it, try adding this property to your TextView:

```
android:elevation="7dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

One can simply use `TextView` by giving custom style for floating.

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fabCounter"
                style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Give it a Try :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/containerpager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_review_order" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna try this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        app:nbMaxTextLength="2" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorprice" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed using constrain layout , I hope it will be helpful to
any of you .

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cvFilterBtnFragDiscover"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:visibility="gone">
    
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivFilterFragDiscover"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_recommended"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvConnCountToolbarWithTab"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_dot"
                    app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/ivFilterFragDiscover"
                    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="35"
                    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="@dimen/_18sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivFilterFragDiscover"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivFilterFragDiscover" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this changes:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/listen_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent"
            app:backgroundTint="#e3e3e3" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```