# Is it possible to set an icon on top of a Floating action button android

Tags: android, material-design

I want to add the items to the cart. The cart will be Floating action button and item count I want to show on top of it. Please help me with this.

I want something like this

[image]

Comment: you can use framelayout to achieve this

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49229997/5855551. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: you can use a simple imageview too alongwith frame or relative layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Badge count on Floating action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639698/badge-count-on-floating-action-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your coordinator layout please add these and you'll have the desired effect

```js
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/panic_fab"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/clip_gradient"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_error_outline_black_24dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/panic_fab1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/notification"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: I got it done completely with this code...with count also...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

button tint to keep background color in your case it will  be orange
src will be the above image which u have in white a dish container 
you can use a frame layout and make another button and align than to top right

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tested this hope this will work for you. Do some changes acording to ua requirements

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_new"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_60"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_10"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_nw"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks...By using above code i got it done...FAB inside FAB. But now how to show count on inner FAB? Any Idea ?

Comment: simply you can count the no of items in your cart.
what i mean is that u vl b using an recycle view or list view inside ua cart .
get there size and set that text to ua button

Comment: instead of using second FAB use textview there and set the circular drawable then u can easily set the text over there

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraintlayout. It will be easier i this case

[image]