# How to add a corner badge for a Floating action button in Android xml?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, floating-action-button

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray_200"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_credit_card_white_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_circle_24"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it looks

[image]

But I want the black dot on top of floating action button. Could someone please help me here?

Comment: Floating button with badges not prefered... Floating elevation hiding you badge... See more info  https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button

Comment: Please check this answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639698/badge-count-on-floating-action-button